# rails 3: How would I write a link_to for a ActionMailer to a just created object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have Recommendations has_many Approvals.

When one approval is made, the user provides an email address for the next user who needs to approve.

In my Approval Model

```
after_save :create_next_approval, :approval_notification


  attr_accessor :next_approver_email

  def recently_approved?
      self.approved_changed? && self.approved?
    end

    def create_next_approval
      #self.recommendations.create :email => self.next_approver_email if next_approver_email.present? && recently_approved?

      next_approval = self.recommendation.approvals.build(:email => self.next_approver_email)
      next_approval.save  if next_approver_email.present? && recently_approved? 
    end
 private
  def approval_notification
    ApprovalMailer.needs_approval(self).deliver
  end
```

In the create_next_approval method, I am saving the next_approval.  I am then sending an email to the next_approver_email address asking them to come approve the recommendation.

I am saving this approval here and I need to link to it in the email being sent out... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly. You need to link to the Approval that you just saved. So this would be `self`.

In that case something like this would work in your email if you have normal routes setup: `<%= link_to "approval link", approval_path(self) %>`

Let me know if I'm following correctly.

Comment: my routes https://gist.github.com/1502681, and I didn't know I could call self in a view like that

Comment: Yes, with those routes, TJ is correct. Because you're passing self to the view as an attribute of a method, it's available for your use.